# Returning an array of variable size in c from a function

Tags: c, function

So i want to return an array of a size `n` (variable) which my function has as input. I know that in order to return arrays in C I have to define them `static`, but the problem is that `n` is a variable and thus I get an error. I thought of actually using `malloc`/`calloc` but then I won't be able to `free` them after the function returns the array. Please take note that I'm not allowed to change anything on `main()`. Are there any other alternatives which I could use? Thanks in advance.

```
float *Arr( int *a , int n ){
    static float b[ n ];
    return b
}
```

Got to point out that the function will only be called Once,I saw the solution you posted but i noticed you aren't freeing the allocated memory,is it not of much importance when the malloc is called inside a function?

Comment: "but then i won't be able to free them after the function returns the array" if you return a pointer, of course you can.

Comment: Well, understand you are declaring a static VLA (*Variable Length Array*) that from C11 on is optional for the compiler to support -- though many do. Why not just allocate a block of memory sized `n * sizeof (float)` and return a pointer to the allocated block -- and have the caller responsible for freeing the memory when done with it?

Comment: Hallo! I mentioned that i can't change anything on main(),thus all i can do is change stuff within the function.In other words,i can't free the memory outside the function,Because i can't write additional code in main().

Comment: You should supply more context. The attempt to use a static array suggests only one array will exist at a time–each time the function is called, the caller (and any previous callers) is done with the array, and it may be reused. In this case, instead of attempting to define a static array, define a static pointer and initialize it to `NULL`. When the function is called, use `realloc` to get memory of the desired size. This will free old memory and allocate new memory (if needed). It will leave one instance in existence at all times after the first call, but so would a static array.

Comment: No, @DavidC.Rankin, VLA support *in general* is optional since C11, but VLAs cannot be static in any implementation.  The size of a static array has to be known at compile time.

Comment: @Amhereforthestonks - technically, if you are just doing something with the "array of float" return by the function, you can just let the block of memory be freed on `exit`. (since you are calling from `main()`, unless you make repeated calls and assign the return to the same pointer -- there is no chance of a memory-leak)

Comment: @JohnBollinger - yes, that is what I indented that VLA support is optional, I haven't finished finding the cite in the standard that prevents static VLA's.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2) specifies that a VLA shall not be `static`. *"If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type."*

Comment: What is the purpose of function `Arr` ? Is it only to return a pointer on an array of `n` elements ? Do you have multiple arrays to allocate with this function ? If you can’t modify `main` to free the arrays, is it a problem to leave them in the heap until the program terminates ? The given code is not valid. The closest is to use  `malloc`. It’s not as bad as using static for the array. I assume you want `Arr` to return a different array of specified size every time it is called. I understood you can’t add code to free arrays in main, but that won’t be a problem if only few calls to `Arr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important thing to notice here is that this syntax:

```
float arr[n];
```

Allocates an array *on the stack of the current function*. In other words, that array is a *local variable*. Any local variable becomes invalid after the function returns, and therefore returning the array directly is *undefined behavior*. It will most likely cause a crash when trying to access the array from outside the function, if not anything worse.

In addition to that, declaring a variable-length array as `static` is invalid in any case.

If you want to write a function which *creates and returns* any kind of array (dynamically sized or not), the only option you have is to use dynamic allocation through `malloc()` and then return *a pointer to the array* (technically there's also [`alloca()`](https://manned.org/alloca.3) to make dynamic stack allocations, but that would not allow you to return the pointer, and I would also avoid it as it can easily break your program if the allocation is too large).

Here's an example of correct code:

```
float *create_array(size_t n_elements){
    float *arr = malloc(sizeof(float) * n_elements);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        // Memory could not be allocated, handle the error appropriately.
    }

    return arr;
}
```

In this case, `malloc()` is reserving memory *outside* of the local stack of the function, *in the heap*. The result is a pointer that can be freely returned and passed around without any problem, since that area of memory keeps being valid after the function returns (until it is released). When you're done working with the data, you can release the allocated memory by calling `free()`:

```
float *arr = create_array(100);
// ...
free(arr);
```

If you don't have a way to release the memory through `free()` after using `malloc()`, that's a problem in the long run, but in general, it is not a strict requirement: if your array is always needed, from its creation until the exit of the program, then there's no need to explicitly `free()` it, since memory is automatically released when the program terminates.

If your function needs to be called more than once or needs to create significantly sized arrays that are only useful in part of the program and should therefore be discarded when no longer in use, then I'm afraid there's no good way of doing it. You should use `free()` in that case.

---

To answer your question precisely:

> Please take note that I'm not allowed to change anything on main(). Are there any other alternatives which I could use?

No, there are no other better alternatives. The only correct approach here is to dynamically allocate the array through `malloc()`. The fact that you cannot `free` it afterwards is a different kind of problem.

Comment: The OP said that he can’t add `free(arr)` to main. But that’s not a problem as long as the total allocated storage is "reasonable". At least your proposal is better than declaring the array static. It wouldn’t be worse.

Answer (score 2):

> So i want to return an array of a size n(variable) which my function
>   has as input,

You can't, because C functions cannot return arrays *at all*.  They can, and some do, return *pointers*, however, as your function is declared to do.  Such a pointer may point to an element of an array.

> i know that in order to return arrays in c i have to
>   define them static,

As long as I am being pedantic, the problem is to do with the lifetime of the object to which the returned pointer points.  If it is an element of an automatically-allocated array, then it, along with the rest of the array, ceases to exist when the function returns.  The caller must not try to dereference such a pointer.

The two other alternatives are

- static allocation, which you get by declaring the variable static *or* by declaring it at file scope, and
- dynamic allocation, which you get by reserving memory via `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or a related function.

Statically allocated objects exist for the entire lifetime of the program, and dynamically allocated ones exist until deallocated.

> but problem is that n is a variable and thus i get
>   an error.

Yes, because variable-length arrays must be automatically allocated.  Static objects exist for the whole run of the program, so the compiler needs to reserve space for them at compile time.

> I thought of actually using malloc/calloc but then i won't be
>   able to free them after the function returns the array.

That's correct, but dynamic allocation is still probably the best solution.  It is not unreasonable for a called function to return a pointer to an allocated object, thus putting the responsibility on its caller to free that object.  Ordinarily, that would be a well-documented characteristic of the function, so that its callers know that such responsibility comes with calling the function.

Moreover, although it's a bit untidy, if your function is to be called only once then it may be acceptable to just allow the program to terminate *without* freeing the array.  The host operating system can generally be relied upon to clean up the mess.

> Please take
>   note that im not allowed to change anything on main(),are there any
>   other alternatives which i could use?

If you have or can impose a bound on the maximum value of `n` then you can declare a static array of that maximum size or longer, and return a pointer to that.  The caller is receiving a *pointer*, remember, not an array, so it can't tell how long the pointed-to array actually is.  All it knows is that the function promises `n` accessible elements.

Note well that there is a crucial difference between the dynamic allocation and static allocation alternatives: in the latter case, the function returns a pointer to *the same* array on every call.  This is not inherently wrong, but it can be problematic.  If implemented, it is a characteristic of the function that should be both intentional and well-documented.

Comment: I guess i will go with the malloc/calloc one,the function will only be called once and for a reasonable amount of integers so it should be fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If want an array of `n` `float`s where `n` is dynamic, you can either create a 
variadic-length array (VLA):

```
void some_function(...)
{
    //...
    float b[ n ]; //allocate b on the stack
    //...

}
```

in which case there would be no function call for the allocation, or you can allocate it dynamically, e.g., with `malloc` or `calloc`, and then free it after you're done with it.

```
  float *b = malloc(sizeof(*b)*n);
```

A dynamic (`malloc`/`calloc`) allocation may be wrapped in a function that returns a pointer to the allocated memory (the wrapper may do some initializations on the allocated memory after the memory has been successfully allocated). A VLA allocation may not, because a VLA ends its lifetime at the end of its nearest enclosing block ([C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects(p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p7)).

If you do end up wrapping a `malloc`/`calloc` call in a "constructor" function like your `float *Arr(void)`, then you obviously should not `free` the to-be-returned allocated memory inside `Arr`–`Arr`'s caller would be responsible for `free`ing the result (unless it passed the responsibility over to some other part of the program):

```
float *Arr( int n, ... 
       /*some params to maybe initialize the array with ?*/ )
{
    float *r; if (!(r=malloc(sizeof(*r)*n)) return NULL;
    //...
    //do some initializations on r
    //...
    return r; //the caller should free it
}
```

Comment: He did seem to want to pass the size in as a parameter. also I think he weanted to use the new array somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you could use malloc to reserve memory for your n sized array

Like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float * arr(int * a, int n ) {
    float *fp = malloc ( (size_t) sizeof(float)*n);
    if (!fp) printf("Oh no! Run out of memory\n");
    return fp;
}

int main () {

    int i;
    float * fpp = arr(&i,200);

    printf("the float array is located at %p in memory\n",  fpp);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Dynamic allocation certainly seems like the best available option, but this would be a stronger answer if it addressed why the OP's attempted approach doesn't work.

Comment: And also stronger if it actually validated the allocation... (what of `a` as the parameter? suggest clarifying if there should be a `return memcpy (fp, a, n * sizeof *fp);` instead.)

Comment: Why casting the return value of `sizeof` to `size_t` ? It’s already of type `size_t`. Also the `printf` should use `%p` for pointers and not `%lx`. You then also won’t need the cast to `long`.

Comment: chmike, valid yup sizeof() does return a size_t. I just do these things to hide from showers of warnings!

Comment: chmike. %p.... thanks did not know that one. learnt my C from K&R back in '84 so good to learn new things :)

Comment: Technically, `%p` expects a `void *` value, so `fpp` ought to be cast to `(void *)` in that `printf` call.

Comment: @user50619 *I just do these things to hide from showers of warnings!*  What compiler requires you to cast the return from `sizeof()` to `size_t`???

Comment: @user50619 `sizeof` is an operator in C, but the wording "sizeof() does return a size_t" gives the impression that it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is:

- have a function that provides (space for) an array with a variable number of elements,
- that the caller is not responsible for freeing,
- that there only needs to be one instance of at a time.

In this case, instead of attempting to define a static array, you can use a static pointer to manage memory allocated and freed with `realloc` as needed to adjust the size, as shown in the code below. This will leave one instance in existence at all times after the first call, but so would a static array.

This might not be a good design (it depends on circumstances not stated in the question), but it seems to match what was requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float *Arr(int *a , int n)
{
    //  Keep a static pointer to memory, with no memory allocated initially.
    static float *b = NULL;

    /*  When we want n elements, use realloc to release the old memory, if any,
        and allocate new memory.
    */
    float *t = realloc(b, n * sizeof *t);

    //  Fail if the memory allocation failed.
    if (!t)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory in Arr.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Return the new memory.
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Hallo! Yeah there is a misunderstanding here,i didn't define the variable static because i wanted it to hold its value each and every time someone calls the function.I did it because i wanted it to hold its value after the function exits, so i can do stuff with the returned pointer.Now since you are using memory allocated from the Heap,there is no reason to define them static,but i get why you are using it in your code and thank you for your recommendation.I ended up just using malloc as John B. and some others suggested and it worked fine.